# How to disable / re-enable all click/touch/mouse events on an html element and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent HTML element with various links, SVGs, text within it at various levels. When a certain link in the parent element is clicked, I'm trying to fade it 50% and disable any further interaction with it from touch / mouse events until it's re-enabled.

My code is complex and spaghetti-like so here is a very simple example:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.container a').on({
    // I'm just showing click below for simplicity, I'll be adding some handling for mouse/touch events.
    click: function(e) {
      $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
      $('.info').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    }
  });

  $('.info a').on({
    click: function(e) {
      $('.info').fadeOut();
      $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #123435;
  padding: 1em;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  background-color: #435123;
  padding: 1em;
}
.container a,
.info,
.info a {
  color: #bbc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Show Info (click me)</a>
  <br>
  <a href="thingy1.htm">Other Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="info">
  Some info (div.container and all it's contents now need to be totally disabled)
  <br>
  <a href="#">Hide Info</a>
  <br>
</div>
```

### What I've tried

When `container` is faded I've attempted to set disabled attributes on all children, which works for any form inputs, but not for links.

I've also tried adding a 'faded' class and then checking for it like so:

```
$('.container:not(.faded) a').on({
  click: function(e) {
    $('.container').addClass("faded").fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
    $('.info').fadeTo("slow", 1);
  }
});
```

..but it seems that the 'on' action doesn't take into account the new class for the selector.. or something!

Help please. I'm very happy to consider a completely different way to tackle this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to really disable everything, not just the event handlers added with javascript, you have to make sure even all the default actions are prevented.

The easy way to make sure **all** interaction with an element is disabled, is to put an other element on top of it, or by using CSS to disable all pointer-events

In modern browsers *(from IE 11 and up)* you can use pointer-events

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container a').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 0.5).css('pointer-events', 'none');
      $('.info').fadeTo("slow", 1);
  });

  $('.info a').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.info').fadeOut();
      $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 1).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #123435;
  padding: 1em;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  background-color: #435123;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container a, .info, .info a {
  color: #bbc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <a href="#">Show Info (click me)</a>
  <br> <a href="thingy1.htm">Other Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="info">Some info (div.container and all it's contents now need to be totally disabled)
  <br> <a href="#">Hide Info</a>
  <br>
</div>
```

In older browsers (IE 10 and down), you'll probably have to use an overlay that covers all the other elements

```js
$('.container a').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.info').fadeTo("slow", 1);

  var container = $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
  var overlay   = container.clone(false);

  overlay.empty().prop('id', 'overlay').css({
    cssText    : container.css('cssText'),
    top        : container.position().left,
    left       : container.position().top,
    position   : 'absolute',
    background : 'transparent'
  }).appendTo(container.parent());
});

$('.info a').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.info').fadeOut();
  $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 1);
  $('#overlay').remove();
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #123435;
  padding: 1em;
}

.info {
  display: none;
  background-color: #435123;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container a, .info, .info a {
  color: #bbc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <a href="#">Show Info (click me)</a>
  <br> <a href="thingy1.htm">Other Link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="info">Some info (div.container and all it's contents now need to be totally disabled)
  <br> <a href="#">Hide Info</a>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: In your first example you remove pointer events with  `.css('pointer-events','none');`. It is worth noting that to put them back you need `.css({ 'pointer-events': 'auto' });` as shown in the answer by Olaf Now.

Comment: Please don't conflate "modern browser" and "Internet Explorer"... it's kinda confusing

Answer (score 4):

You can use flags (read @Banana's answer).
Also, you can (un)handle events using jQuery:

```
// idea
$('#selector').on('event.name', function(){
    // do something
    // then remove event
    $(this).off('.name');
});

// example
$('#selector').on('click.eventsGroup1', function(){
    // do something
    // then remove event
    $(this).off('.eventsGroup1');
});
```

You have all the information you need at [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something, I had no idea .off() existed.

Answer (score 4):

with css you can specify if an element can receive mouse events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

to turn mouse events off:

```
$(".container a").css({ "pointer-events": "none" });
```

turning them on again:

```
$(".container a").css({ "pointer-events": "auto" });
```

Answer (score 4):

As many posters have noted you can use the pointer-events property to prevent clicks. Since inline styles are an evil thing I will post a CSS solution: Add a class: "disable-click" to the element and add the CSS code :

```
.disable-click {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
}
.disable-click * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.disable-click:before {
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

This should prevent users from being able to interact with the container and it's children using click and touch events. This works best on modern browsers but I also added the pseudo element "mask" which will provide similar functionality on older bowsers as well.

Please note: this will not always prevent users from being able to tab into a "disabled" element using the keyboard. This is especially true for older browsers.

Comment: This is a really nice and simple workaround. I'm going for something similar but with the js fallback as well, but thanks a lot for the clever suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I've ended up with adding this class to the `body` and using pseudo `:after` instead of `:before`

Answer (score 3):

Flags are your best friends:

```
var ClicksEnabled=true;
$('.container a').on({
     click: function (e) {
         if(ClicksEnabled){
             $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
             $('.info').fadeTo("slow", 1);
             ClicksEnabled=false;
         }
     }
 });

$('.container').on("click", "*", function (e) {
    if (!ClicksEnabled) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here is your fixed snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  var ClicksEnabled = true;
  $('.container a.show_info').on({
    click: function(e) {
      if (ClicksEnabled) {
        $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
        $('.info').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        ClicksEnabled = false;
      }
    }
  });

  $('.container').on("click", "*", function(e) {
    if (!ClicksEnabled) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $('.info a').on({
    click: function(e) {
      if (!ClicksEnabled) {
        $('.info').fadeOut();
        $('.container').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        ClicksEnabled = true;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #123435;
  padding: 1em;
}
.info {
  display: none;
  background-color: #435123;
  padding: 1em;
}
.container a,
.info,
.info a {
  color: #bbc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> <a class="show_info" href="#">Show Info (click me)</a>

  <br/> <a href="thingy1.htm">Other Link 1</a>

</div>
<div class="info">Some info (div.container and all it's contents now need to be totally disabled)
  <br/> <a href="#">Hide Info</a>

  <br/>
</div>
```